# override .net core embedded resource name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, resx

I am migrating a .net framework winforms application to .net core following instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms

The original project contains some strings in .resx-files, which have been manually added to subfolder called localization. They are defined as Embedded Resource and have ResXFileCodeGenerator defined as custom tool. This generates a strongly typed class that I can use to access the resource and everything works in the .net framework app.

The problem is that when I try to access the resource in the .net core project using the strongly typed helper class I get the following exception:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find the
>   resource MyFormsApp.Localization.Strings.resources

After looking at the generated assembly I can see that resources are being embedded, but with a different name MyFormsAppCore.Localization.Strings.resources, which I assume is the problem. How can I override the embedded resource name or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by changing the default namespace in the .net core app to the name of .net framework app (MyFormsApp in my example).